# How to set the UItablview ticks with the array which i get from backend?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am using the checkmarks in UITableView for language selection and passing those languages to the backend while updating profile.
Now when i login again with the user i also get the languages which i updated from selection. So i want to show the ticks in the UITableview based on the language coming from backend. How is it possible?

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    arrProductSelection = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Afar",@"Abkhazian",@"Afrikaans",@"Amharic",@"Arabic",@"Assamese",@"Aymara",@"Azerbaijani",@"Bashkir",@"Belarusian",@"Bulgarian",@"Bihari",@"Bislama",@"Bengali",@"Bislama",@"Tibetan",@"Breton",@"Bosnian",@"Catalan",@"Cebuano",@"Cherokee",@"Corsican",@"Seselwa",@"Czech",@"Welsh",@"Danish",@"German",@"Dhivehi",@"Dzongkha",@"Greek",@"English",@"Esperanto",@"Spanish",@"Estonian",@"Basque",@"Persian",@"Finnish",@"Fijian",@"Faroese",@"French",@"Frisian",@"Irish",@"Scots Gaelic",@"Galician",@"Guarani",@"Gujarati",@"Manx",@"Hausa",@"Hawaiian",@"Bislama",@"Hindi",@"Hmong",@"Croatian",@"Haitian Creole",@"Hungarian",@"Armenian",@"Interlingua",@"Indonesian",@"Igbo",@"Inupiak",@"Icelandic",@"Italian",@"Inuktitut",@"Hebrew",@"Japanese",@"Javanese",@"Georgian",@"Khasi",@"Kazakh",@"Greenlandic",@"Khmer",@"Kannada",@"Korean",@"Kashmiri",@"Kurdish",@"Kyrgyz",@"Latin",@"Luxembourgish",@"Ganda",@"Limbu",@"Lingala",@"Laothian",@"Lithuanian",@"Latvian",@"Malagasy",@"Mauritian Creole",@"Malagasy",@"Maori",@"Macedonian",@"Malayalam",@"Mongolian",@"Marathi",@"Malay",@"Maltese",@"Burmese",@"Nauru",@"Nepali",@"Dutch",@"Norwegian",@"Ndebele",@"Pedi",@"Nyanja",@"Occitan",@"Oromo",@"Oriya",@"Punjabi",@"Polish",@"Pashto",@"Portuguese",@"Quechua",@"Rhaeto Romance",@"Scots",@"Sindhi",@"Sango",@"Sinhalese",@"Slovak",@"Slovenian",@"Samoan",@"Shona",@"Somali",@"Albanian",@"Serbian",@"Siswant",@"Sesotho",@"Sundanese",@"Swedish",@"Swahili",@"Syriac",@"Tamil",@"Telugu",@"Tajik",@"Thai",@"Tigrinya",@"Turkmen",@"Tagalog",@"Sundanese",@"Tswana",@"Tonga",@"Turkish",@"Tsonga",@"Tatar",@"Uighur",@"Ukrainian",@"Urdu",@"Uzbek",@"Venda",@"Vietnamese",@"Volapuk",@"Waray Philippines",@"Wolof",@"Xhosa",@"WYiddish",@"Yoruba",@"WZhuang",@"Chinese",@"Hant,Chinese",@"Zulu",nil];
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [languageTableView selectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] animated:NO scrollPosition:0];
    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    arrayFetchFromDefaults = [userDefaults objectForKey:@"selectedcheckmark"];
    arrProductSelectDeSelectCheckMark = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:arrayFetchFromDefaults];
    NSLog(@"Array from defaults %@",arrayFetchFromDefaults);
    if(arrProductSelectDeSelectCheckMark.count == 0)
    {
        arrProductSelectDeSelectCheckMark = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        for(int j=0;j<[arrProductSelection count];j++)
        {
            [arrProductSelectDeSelectCheckMark addObject:@"deselected"];

        }
    }

    NSMutableArray *arrSelected = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int i= 0;i< arrayFetchFromDefaults.count ;i++ )
    {
        if([[arrayFetchFromDefaults objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:@"selected"])
        {
            NSLog(@"array array %@",[arrProductSelection objectAtIndex:i]);
            [arrSelected addObject:arrProductSelection[i]];
        }

    }

    self.strSelected = [arrSelected componentsJoinedByString:@","];

    NSLog(@"%@", _strSelected);
    //[self gatherFBIds];
    [languageTableView reloadData];
}

#pragma mark - UITableViewDataSource Methods
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return arrProductSelection.count;
}
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *strCell = @"cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:strCell];
    if(cell==nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:strCell];
    }
    if([[arrProductSelectDeSelectCheckMark objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"deselected"])
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    else
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    cell.textLabel.text = [arrProductSelection objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.tintColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    NSMutableArray *arrSelected = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int i= 0;i< arrayFetchFromDefaults.count ;i++ )
    {
        if([[arrayFetchFromDefaults objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:@"selected"])
        {
            NSLog(@"array array %@",[arrProductSelection objectAtIndex:i]);
            [arrSelected addObject:arrProductSelection[i]];
        }

    }

    self.strSelected = [arrSelected componentsJoinedByString:@","];

    NSLog(@"%@", _strSelected);
   // [self gatherFBIds];
    return cell;
}

#pragma mark - UITableViewDelegate Methods
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];


    @try
    {
        CGPoint touchPoint = [cell convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:languageTableView];
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [languageTableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:touchPoint];
        NSLog(@" Check mark %@",arrProductSelectDeSelectCheckMark);
        if([arrProductSelectDeSelectCheckMark count]==0)
        {
            for(int i=0; i<[arrProductSelection count]; i++)
            {
                [arrProductSelectDeSelectCheckMark addObject:@"deselected"];
            }
        }
        if([[arrProductSelectDeSelectCheckMark objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"deselected"])
        {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
            [arrProductSelectDeSelectCheckMark replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:@"selected"];
             NSLog(@" Check mark 1 %@",arrProductSelectDeSelectCheckMark);
            NSMutableArray *arrSelected = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            for (int i= 0;i< arrProductSelectDeSelectCheckMark.count ;i++ )
            {
                if([[arrProductSelectDeSelectCheckMark objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:@"selected"])
                {
                    NSLog(@"array array %@",[arrProductSelection objectAtIndex:i]);
                    [arrSelected addObject:arrProductSelection[i]];
                }

            }

            self.strSelected = [arrSelected componentsJoinedByString:@","];

            NSLog(@"%@", _strSelected);
        }
        else
        {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
            [arrProductSelectDeSelectCheckMark replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:@"deselected"];
             NSLog(@" Check mark 2 %@",arrProductSelectDeSelectCheckMark);

            NSMutableArray *arrSelected = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            for (int i= 0;i< arrProductSelectDeSelectCheckMark.count ;i++ )
            {
                if([[arrProductSelectDeSelectCheckMark objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:@"selected"])
                {
                    NSLog(@"array array %@",[arrProductSelection objectAtIndex:i]);
                    [arrSelected addObject:arrProductSelection[i]];
                }

            }

            self.strSelected = [arrSelected componentsJoinedByString:@","];

            NSLog(@"%@", _strSelected);
        }

        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [defaults setObject:arrProductSelectDeSelectCheckMark forKey:@"selectedcheckmark"];
        [defaults synchronize];




    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"The exception is-%@",exception);
    }


}
```

Comment: you need to compare the selected language with the list of languages and tick that one.

Comment: While creating the cell in cellForRowAtIndexpath method you can check if the object is in selectedItems array and update it. No need of running a separate for loop

Comment: how it is possible??

Comment: @AshleyRodrigues check my ans if suitable ..

Answer (score 1):

You can add logic in tableview datasource method.

```
   -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        NSString *strCell = @"cell";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:strCell];
        if(cell==nil)
        {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:strCell];
        }

        for(NSString *string in arrProductSelectDeSelectCheckMark)
        {
           if([string isEqualToString:@"SomeString"])
              {
              cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;;
              }
              else
              {
              cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
              }

              //rest of code

              return cell;

              }
```

Modify it as per your need.